# How to transform data of this text file to an excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently setting up a new Poll Result for a Webinar Survey in Webex Application.

I will only able to collect Result in this PollResults.txt (notepad file) and will need to transform this data into an excel table for further analysis. As i will have multiple Poll Results to collect everyday, therefore transforming them into a data table would helps a lot for further compilation/analysis.

I'm thinking about creating an VBA to transform accordingly, but currently has no idea how should i start.

I will share the download link for both of my raw data and expected result file in the download link, appreciate if anyone could guide me on it.

[Link to download files](https://github.com/junyikho0/PollResult)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start importing your txt file into Excel and loop through all the rows then to analyze your data, or try to do it with Regular Expressions (RegEx). Both could work. Both will be tricky and a lot of work, that's not an easy task. • But actually to be honest, your question is a way too broad to give you a good anwser here (see [Ask]).

Comment: Not sure if you need VBA for this. Could just import the text file into Excel (Through `Data` tab). @Pᴇʜ: Not sure if I like this.. theme they have on today.. off putting! :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for your suggestion, yeah is rather tricky, sorry for not providing a rough solution first here, and making the question too broad. Understood that it is really messy, i was just looking if there's any sample solution here.

Comment: @Zac Thanks to you too! I try using import the text file, but im not able to transform it accordingly. Still trying today! Thanks for suggestion too! :)